# MS VS 2013 for Web Local Database using aspx.cs to connect to local database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database-connection

Using MS VS 2013 Express for Web Local Database (also SQL Server Express) using aspx.cs to connect to local database.

When I run the code nothing shows on browser.

The `finance2` table does have data. I have thoroughly scanned google and stackoverflow, so if someone could just give me a link (for example) for a working MS VS 2013 Express for Web Local Database (with local db) that would be fine.

When I tried to debug enclosing the code in try catch blocks - all I could find was browserLink.js  _references.js not found error. Not sure if that would be the root cause.
Show me the errors here (there are no syntax errors):

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void atry()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=   
        (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated  
        Security=True";

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM finance2";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds);

        connection.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            atry();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: are you sure that the `atry()` function is actually executing?

Comment: Yes I added debug.Writeline comments to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace This:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

With This:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Tried GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]. No errors but also nothing displayed. I am sure that the table has data!Also tried opening in IE instead of Chrome.